# Issues adding elements to an Arraylist. JSoup Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, jsoup, indexoutofboundsexception

2I need a little help with this code. I'm getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException. I know why but I'm stuck trying to fix it. Issue: eMain.getElementsByClass("trA1").size() = 8 and eMain.getElementsByClass("trA2").size() = 7 (The sizes many very, but trA1 is always bigger than trA2). I need to add each element to and ArrayList as add(trA1), add(trA2), add(trA1), add(trA2)...... (I'm using the for loop for that) but when I get to element 8, I get the exception because there is no trA2 element 8. I tried an If statement to check if the element is null or "" but I still get the exception. any ideas.

```
                // game list data
            if (!eMain.equals("")) {
                for (int i=0; i < eMain.getElementsByClass("trA1").size(); i++) {
                    // check if AsyncTask was cancelled
                    if (isCancelled())
                        break;

                    if (eMain.getElementsByClass("trA1").select("strong").get(i).text() != null) {
                        // get string data
                        String titleA1 = eMain.getElementsByClass("trA1").select("strong").get(i).text();
                        String achAmountA1 =  eMain.getElementsByClass("trA1").select("td[align]").get(mAchAmountCounter).text();
                        String gsAmountA1 = eMain.getElementsByClass("trA1").select("td[align]").get(mGsAmountCounter).text();
                        String aPageLinkA1 = eMain.getElementsByClass("trA1").select("td a").get(mPageLinkCounter).attr("abs:href");
                        String iconSrcA1 = eMain.getElementsByClass("trA1").select("td a img").get(i).attr("abs:src");

                        // create game object
                        GameObject gameObjectA1 = new GameObject();
                        gameObjectA1.setGlTitle(titleA1);
                        gameObjectA1.setGlAchAmount(achAmountA1 + " achievements");
                        gameObjectA1.setGlGSAmount(gsAmountA1 + " gamer score");
                        gameObjectA1.setGlAchPageUrl(aPageLinkA1);
                        gameObjectA1.setGlIcon(iconSrcA1);
                        mGameObjectList.add(gameObjectA1);
                    }

                    if (eMain.getElementsByClass("trA2").select("strong").get(i).text() != null) {
                        String titleA2 = eMain.getElementsByClass("trA2").select("strong").get(i).text();
                        String achAmountA2 =  eMain.getElementsByClass("trA2").select("td[align]").get(mAchAmountCounter).text();
                        String gsAmountA2 = eMain.getElementsByClass("trA2").select("td[align]").get(mGsAmountCounter).text();
                        String aPageLinkA2 = eMain.getElementsByClass("trA2").select("td a").get(mPageLinkCounter).attr("abs:href");
                        String iconSrcA2 = eMain.getElementsByClass("trA2").select("td a img").get(i).attr("abs:src");

                        GameObject gameObjectA2 = new GameObject();
                        gameObjectA2.setGlTitle(titleA2);
                        gameObjectA2.setGlAchAmount(achAmountA2 + " achievements");
                        gameObjectA2.setGlGSAmount(gsAmountA2 + " gamer score");
                        gameObjectA2.setGlAchPageUrl(aPageLinkA2);
                        gameObjectA2.setGlIcon(iconSrcA2);
                        mGameObjectList.add(gameObjectA2);
                    }

                    // counters
                    mPageLinkCounter += 3;
                    mAchAmountCounter += 2;
                    mGsAmountCounter += 2;

                    // update progress bar
                    publishProgress((100 / (Integer) Math.round(eA1.size())));
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please include the the full stack trace in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the size of "trA2" is always less than that of "trA1" you can do this as a fix.

Right before the for loop, declare:

```
final int size2 = eMain.getElementsByClass("trA2").size();
```

In the for loop, change:

```
if (eMain.getElementsByClass("trA2").select("strong").get(i).text() != null)
```

to:

```
if (i < size2 && eMain.getElementsByClass("trA2").select("strong").get(i).text() != null)
```

Offtopic but for the sake of code clarity, you might want to declare two variables `element1` and `element2` to `eMain.getElementsByClass("trA1")` and `eMain.getElementsByClass("trAeMain.getElementsByClass("trA2")` respectively right before the for loop as well, in order to make your code clearer.

Comment: No problem ;) But try and introduce more local variables, it will help unclutter the code